# How do you get this to remove the value that the user wants to remove from the list and then return the new list values

Tags: python

```
def main():

    values = []
    numbers = get_Values(values)

    print("The numbers in the list are:")
    print(numbers)
    removeList = remove_Value_List(values)
    print(removeList)

def get_Values(values): #This asks the user to enter all the values they want to be in the list
    again = "y"

    while again == "y":
        num = float(input("Enter a number:"))
        values.append(num)

        print("Do you want to add another number?")
        again = input("y = yes, anything else = no:")
        print()

    return values

def remove_Value_List(values): #This asks the user which value they want to remove from the list
    print("Here are the numbers in the list:")
    print(values)
    number_list = input("Which value should I remove?")

    try:
        values.remove(number_list)
        print("Here is the revised list:")       
        return values
    except ValueError:
        print("That item is not found in the list.")
        number_list = input("which value should I remove?")

main()
```

How do you get this to remove the value that the user wants to remove from the list and then return the new list values?

Comment: what is not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = float(input("Enter a number:"))
values.append(num)
```

When you add numbers to the list you convert them to floats.

```
number_list = input("Which value should I remove?")
values.remove(number_list)
```

When you try to remove them you don't have the float conversion, so it tries to remove the string the user typed. That will never remove anything as the list doesn't contain strings.

Comment: Which in turn should always throw that `ValueError` exception, regardless of input. Since the `except` block doesn't return anything, I think it even sets `removeList` to `None`!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do the removal in the function then you need to do a loop. otherwise the except would fall through to a return of None. I see that this exits as soon as one value has been removed. I will assum that is the way you want it.

```
def remove_Value_List(values): 
  #This asks the user which value they want to remove from the list
  print("Here are the numbers in the list:")
  print(values)
  # Now ask which numbers to remove
  while True:
    try:
      number_list = input("Which value should I remove?")
      values.remove(number_list)
      print("Here is the revised list:")       
      return values # You can use break here
    except ValueError:
      print("That item is not found in the list.")
      continue
  # If you used break in the while put return values here 
  # return values if break was used to exit the loop
```

However, there is another way to do it. You set up two definitions for functions to create the two lists. You should make the function to create the removal list (remove_Value_List()) in the same way that you create the list for the number (get_Values()). You should not check for the members of the removal list to be in the numbers list because these are independent functions and you may add something to the numbers list later. You should write the two functions to run on their own.

After you have completely build the two lists, **then** go through the remove_List and redo the numbers list. If you want to have this purged list as a third one, rather than changing numbers, first do a copy

```
newnumbers = numbers[:] 
for x in removeList: 
  if x in newnumbers: 
    newnumbers.remove(x)
```

You can of course use the try: except method as well but the above avoids it.

```
newnumbers = numbers[:]
for x in removeList:
  try:
    newnumbers.remove(x)
  except ValueError:
    continue
```

Comment: @2rs2ts I deleted the original and redid it to explain properly. I explain here why the try except that he used is not valid.